# How to install npm dependency module when the module published in local registry domain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a module which I published in my custom registry domain, eg. http://my-custom-npm-registry.com, and I can publish my module there.
I have a problem with dependencies which I have in my published module, eg.

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.3"
},
```

After trying to install my published module like`

```
npm install my-published-module --save --registry=http://my-custom-npm-registry.com
```

I have got an error

```
npm http fetch GET 404 registry=http://my-custom-npm-registry.com/angular2-text-mask 170ms
```

Seems npm tries to get dependency module from my registry domain, and I couldn't find a solution to fix it.

How can I add a check in my script to see if there is a module in my registry like dependency module try to install it, if not try to install from global registry of npm "https://registry.npmjs.org/" ?

Comment: what custom registry are you using? is it an open source custom registry or a proprietary one ? or are you using a git server directly?

Comment: Why do you need custom npm registry? Solution can be related to actual need

Comment: No I'm not using git server, it's a not open source, it's kind of local registry domain proprietary one

Comment: I don't want to share my module in global npm registry @PranavSingh

Comment: You don't need to, you can have local module in npm package like : `"react-click-outside": "git+https://github.com/pranavq212/react-click-outside.git",` it can be your custom domain, rest can be from npm server

Comment: The problem is that now I can clone your module and use, but I don't want my module be used by another person, except the person I would like to.

Comment: limit your custom server for your application IP only & use in package.json. I have used github just for example, you can use custom module there

Comment: Oh , ok @PranavSingh, I understand you, only I don't know how to use it in my package.json ?

Comment: Posted answer, please check

Answer (score 0):

For me, I will set the registry to the global registry of npm [https://registry.npmjs.org/](https://registry.npmjs.org) like usual. Then install my custom package from my own registry. Something like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.3",
    "my-published-module": "http://my-custom-npm-registry.com/my-published-module"
},
```

The url of the module may be different depends on how your store the module on your server.

The second possibility is to deploy your private registry using https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia. It will auto proxy the public package to npmjs.org.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for answer @Dat Tran, but "my-custom-npm-registry.com" is kind of a database like "https://registry.npmjs.org/"

Comment: If your private registry is hosted by you. You can think of moving it to system like sinopia. It works like the npmjs + proxy to npmjs.

Comment: I would not recommend sinopia nowadays, it's a dead project. Try with Verdaccio instead. https://verdaccio.org/

Answer (score 0):

As per you comment, you can have some or particular package from your custom domain module and rest of module can be from npm server like :

```
"dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react-click-outside": "git+https://github.com/pranavq212/react-click-outside.git",
    "my-published-module": "http://my-custom-npm-registry.com/angular2-text-mask"
}
```

Make sure http://my-custom-npm-registry.com/angular2-text-mask path exists & have required compiled files for package module

Now don't use `--registry` tag in `npm install`.

Use `npm install my-published-module --save`

Comment: Great answer @Pranav Singh, it will help me more, but only the problem is that my-custom-domain is not a domain which stores my module's source code with package.json, but it is a registry like domain, which has a database, and setting --registry helps my domain to find a version of my module from database.

Comment: In that case also you can try using url, it will give latest version like npm registry `https://registry.npmjs.org/angular2-text-mask`, try it & see if it works for custom registry too.